# ASP MVC Dynamically output model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a few pages that wrap some 3rd party API calls and display the result in a table.

The resultant view is always the same, iterate through a custom class's properties and display there values in tabular form

```
@if (Model.Response.items != null && Model.Response.items.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Response.items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="200px">Reference</td>
            <td>@item.Reference</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>@item.Amount</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This "Response" object is generated from an XML response and can contain multiple nested properties.
Is it possible within my view to reflectively iterate the object for all public properties and display them in a table to save me time in future?

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection (`@using System.Reflection;`).

```
        foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            // property.Name
            // property.GetValue(...)
        }
```

Comment: This does help me get the first level, but i need to nest this loop for each non primitive type